# Spring log if cache is called for @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, caching, logging

I have a simple spring 3.2 web application, which is connected to a MySQL db. My question is simple: I have method in dao, which is annotated with @Cacheable. Is there a way to log if the method goes to db, or its result is loaded from cache? For example, I'd like to see the following log:

```
Object with id 'x' was retrieved from database at 23:44:30 / 2015....
Object with id 'x' was retrived from cache at...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Spring logs out cache hits and misses under the `org.springframework.cache` category at `TRACE` level.

Comment: I have enabled this and all I get are entries like 

```Computed cache key 'SimpleKey foo' for operation bar```

Is there something else I need to enable in order to see hits/misses? I'm using Caffeine but can't find a way of getting that to log them either

Answer (score 1):

you can a log message in your service layer if there's going to be a call to your persistence layer.  here's a method from some code i'm working where i'm doing this.  I only get a log entry when the cache isn't hit.

```
@Cacheable(value = CACHE_PICO)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@PostAuthorize(PICO_READ + OR + ALLOWED_FOR_ADMIN)
public Pico get(long id) {
    log.info("cached missed for pico {}", id);
    return _picoRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Comment: This way you have to modify each of your cacheable methods

Answer (score 0):

if u use application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cache: TRACE
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [log4jdbc](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc) ([docu](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)) - it is wrapper around your normal jdbc connection that logs every executed statement.

Comment: I know, but i want to see if the cache was called. In this case i will not see anything. I hope you understad

Comment: But you hopefully know when it is invoked, so every inovation without DB log is resoved by the cache.